Date localization based on geographic server location using PHP
I know that in Android development if you get a date it is returned based on the phone's Locale!
I have an android app that communicates with a server(whose geographic location can change).
The server returns a date that determines the end of the purchase benefit. The date is returned using the following PHP code:
$today = date_create();

date_modify($today,"+7 days");

$modified_date = date_format($today,"m/d/y");

echo "record created with date={$modified_date}";

Now, I am no expert in using PHP code, but it makes me think if somehow, just like in Android, will this modified date be localized based on the server geographic location?
I need everything to be based on Locale.US if not the date verifications will break.

You're using the word locale but it sounds like you're talking about timezones. Do you mean en-US as it pertains to language and formatting? Or do you mean an American timezone?

if it is timezones you're talking about, then set the server to UTC (regardless of actual geographical location, which  should be completely irrelevant) and store all dates as such. When the client sends dates, include the phones timezone so you can convert them to UTC when you receive them on the server. When the phone gets dates from the server, they will always be UTC and you can convert them to the phones local timezone.

@AlexHowansky yes I mean TimeZones

@M.Eriksson Ok your solution sounds right! How would I set the server to UTC using PHP. How should I modify the PHP code so it returns UTC. The client does not send the actual date when purchase was made. The actual date of purchase is the variable $today

If you google "set timezone in PHP" you will find the answer instantly. I usually set the actual server (not just PHP) to UTC. If the server is set to UTC and you have saved all dates as such, then the server will also return it.

@M.Eriksson ok so setting the server to UTC should be a settings that the webhost manages. It should be under a settings page for the server

@M.Eriksson yes but I think my code up there already forces the date to be in a specific format! the 'm/d/y' so is irrelevant if I set the server time to UTC. The code should be able to convert whatever time in whatever format the server returns!

The date.timezone setting in your php.ini file will determine the default timezone. This is what you'll get if you call date_create() without the optional second parameter, and it might match the server's actual physical location, but don't bet on it.

@M.Eriksson I need a friend(in a far away place) that will type my server URL that echos that date and see the format of the time!

@AlexHowansky ok I will look for that setting thanks!

I would not rely on that setting. Rather, I would recommend always explicitly providing a timezone as the second parameter, or calling date_default_timezone_set() at the start of the script. Then it doesn't matter what that setting is, and your code is more portable.

Note that the remote user's location and timezone will have zero effect on the output of this script. PHP is server side only.

@AlexHowansky thanks then I will implement both within the code and the overall website. Since I am in the eastern USA I set my time zone to EDT

"yes but I think my code up there already forces the date to be in a specific format! the 'm/d/y' so is irrelevant if I set the server time to UTC" - Please read up on the terminology. Date formats are not the same as time zones which are not the same as locale or localization.

" I need a friend(in a far away place) that will type my server URL that echos that date and see the format of the time!" - Again, the format has nothing to do with it. And the server returns what the server returns, no matter where the client is located. It's up to the clients (your app, web site front end etc) to translate the dates it gets from the server into the local time zone for the user. That's why it's recommended to use UTC, since it's essentially the "base time" that time zones use as reference. You can use any time zone on the server, but I would recommend UTC.

The below Sample Code is an example of converting Locale date to US Timezone
$date = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')); 
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Enter any place in DateTimeZone() whose local Timezone is required.
I answered as much as I did understand of your Problem, If I'm wrong kindly notify me.

Thank you! I will try your code and let you know.
